The number of roots in the interval $0\leq x\leq2\pi$
Given if $$f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}\cos(x)+a_{2}\cos(2x)+\cdots+a_{n}\cos(nx)$$
where $a_{0}, a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}$ are non-zero real numbers and $$a_{n}>\lvert a_{0}\rvert+\lvert a_{1}\rvert+\cdots \lvert a_{n-1}\rvert$$
then the number of roots of $f(x)$ in the interval $0\le x\le 2\pi$ is:
I can only say that the function is less than $2a_{n}$. What I have tried is that to find the number of times the function tries to change its sign which can give me the number of roots. How can we solve this problem?
There is a duplicate of the question which does not provide me any idea how to solve the problems . I still cannot understand anything about the number of roots of the problems ?
My observation and thought: Using the modulus inequality we can show $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq a_{n}+ \lvert a_{n}cos(nx) \rvert$. So for $cos(nx)=\pm1$ we can get $2n$ roots and hence $f(x)$ will have the same number of roots. Is this argument true? Thank you

Show that the number of roots will be the same as the number of roots for $\cos (nx)=0$

This what I am unable to solve @Vasili.

For $n=2$: $\cos 2x=1 \implies x=-2\pi, \pi, 0, \pi, 2\pi$, $\cos 2x=-1 \implies$  $x=-\frac{3\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}$. Assume that $a_2 >0$. Do you see that $f(-2\pi)>0, f(-\frac{3\pi}{2}) <0$ so there is a root on that interval?

@Vasili I want to know how the function f(x) will have the same root as cos nx . How to find the correlation.

Not the same root but the same number of roots

@Vasili yes , my mistake how can we show they have the same number of roots?
